# What is this "BTree" variant being used in PST files?

Tags: data-structures, outlook, b-tree, pst

I've been working on parsing PST files with the help of https://www.five-ten-sg.com/libpst/rn01re06.html and https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/openspecification/2010/11/30/ms-pst-how-to-navigate-the-node-btree/ where they refer to it as a BTree, but it doesn't seem to follow the rules I can find for regular BTrees.

I've mapped it so I can show it visually

[image: BTree like thing]

Basically its made up of nodes that contain children (up to 20) and those are the same structure and so on until the leaf nodes, which are different, but the internal nodes aren't used for any actual data storing and seem to (sometimes) share the keys of the the first node in their children.

I'm asking because I'm trying to find out common ways of inserting, deleting, searching this data but regular BTree algorithms like on https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/b-tree-set-1-introduction-2/ aren't working since this data doesn't seem to be structured in exactly the same way.

I've modified the search algorithm to traverse the current children in reverse until I find a child with an ID less than or equal to the one I'm searching for, and then look at that nodes children, which is working great but I'd rather not reinvent the wheel here and miss things if I don't have to.

Comment: In what way does the PST BTree layout differ from that described in the GeeksforGeeks article? I don't see any real difference between what you show and what the article describes.

Comment: @JimMischel the first picture they show shows that all the nodes contain unique keys, unlike this one where the root node can have a key matching a leaf node key, and also this one shows child nodes under a node, where the picture in that link shows 3 keys and 4 sets of children?

Comment: Remember, only the leaf nodes contain actual data. The nodes at higher levels are just signposts. The root, for example, says, "All leaf nodes with keys less than or equal to 4 are to the left. All leaf nodes with keys greater than or equal to 78 are to the right. All leaf nodes with values between 4 and 78 (non-inclusive) are in the middle subtree."

Comment: @JimMischel but there is no "less than" here, the highest node key is the lowest key in its subtree, there's never anything less or "to the left of"

Comment: Please explain what "the highest node key is the lowest key in its subtree" means. Explain using an example from the figure you posted.

Comment: @JimMischel so in the first root node, it has an ID of 4, which means that nothing in its subtree is less than 4 (and the lowest node key value is most likely equal to 4), and if you go into that first root nodes subtree, it's second internal node has an ID, and the lowest element in its subtree is 6, nothing less than that, and they all follow this pattern

Comment: I see. Then perhaps the `4` means "greater than or equal to 4, but less than 8." That would make more sense.

Comment: @JimMischel something like that, when I search this tree, I start at the last root node and go backwards until I find the first node who's ID is less than or equal to the one I'm looking for, and repeat, and that seems to work perfectly, which isn't the standard search algorithm

Answer (score 0):

Here is a different display which I think shows more clearly that this is a standard B-Tree. The B-Tree index (Node or Block index) in the intermediate node is the index of the lowest leaf under the node; a Node or Block index can hence be found easily. (Disclaimer - this image was generated from a [tool I developed](https://github.com/Jmcleodfoss/pstreader/tree/master/explorer).)

[image]